# How much Curie temperature is obtained according to the Stoner model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, temperature, critical-phenomena, ferromagnetism

In Stoner model for itinarant ferromagnetism, the spin ordering of electrons is caused by the Coulomb interaction $U$ for onsite repulsion leading to the reduction of total energy against to the enhanced kinetic energy. If one can induce an imbalence $\delta n$ between total amount of spin-up and spin-down electrons, the kinetic energy $E_k$ will increase with $\delta E_k = \frac{1}{D_F} (\delta n)^2$ while the Coulomb repulsion energy will change with $\delta E_C = -U(\delta n)^2$. Therefore, we can normally obtain the **Stoner criterion** for itinerant Ferromagnetism:
$$\delta E = \delta E_k + \delta E_C = \frac{1}{D_F} (\delta n)^2(1 - D_F U) $$
in which the $D_F U>1$ corresponds to the ferromagnetism, while $D_F U<1$ corresponds to the paramagnetism.

I survey in many textbooks and note on interent, however, most of documents only domenstate above criterion, the value of estimated Curie temperature is remained elusive for me.

In particular, above consideration is not fully addressed all my confusions. If an imbalence $\delta n$ is intruduced by some perturbation, the total energy decreases without any limitation, and finally all spin will be aligned and extremely robust against thermal fluctuation, which will thus will result to an inceadiblely high Curie temperature.

So, how much Curie tempeature should be in Stoner model ?

Comment: At first glance, it seems that the Stoner criterion is not directly related to Curie temperature. This temperature can be rougly estimated in simple spin-spin interaction Hamiltonian and the Stoner criterion affects only on a multiplier in resulting answer. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Or you mean the following Hamiltonian, $H=\sum_{k,\sigma}\left(\epsilon_k+I\langle n_{-\sigma}\rangle\right)c_{k\sigma}^{\dagger}c_{k\sigma}$?

Comment: Did you read this paper with 245 citations https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pssa.2211180133 ?

Comment: Since this has received no answers in so many months, I thought I'd let you know that Curie temperature questions have been fairly well-received here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curie-temperature

Answer (score 0):

Low-effort answer, but since this was the first search engine hit when I was wondering the same thing, this might help others.

In the Stoner model, the Curie temperature is defined as the temperature at which:

$$I(E_F) \int_{-x}^x \frac{\partial f(E)}{\partial E} N(E) \mathrm{d}E + 1 = 0$$

with $F(E)$ the Fermi-Dirac distribution and $N(E)$ the density of states per spin and per atom (in units of 1/J). With the notations of the question, that means the temperature for which $D_F U = 1$.

From the introduction of ["The Curie temperature of the ferromagnetic transition metals and their compounds", 1987, by Mohn and Wohlfarth](https://www.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4608/17/12/016):

> the Curie temperatures, determined from the Stoner model and from the ground state properties and the fine structure of the density of states at the Fermi energy, are much too high. Gunnarsson (1976) reported values of the Stoner Curie temperature $T_C^S$ as being equal to 4400-6300 K for Fe and 2900 K for Ni. The reason for these unrealistically high values is not entirely due to the defects of the Stoner theory. Gunnarsson derived his values from band-structure calculations [which] leads to overestimates of the exchange splitting $\Delta E$ [and] also leads to an overestimation of the Curie temperature. Oles and Stollhoff (1986) and Stollhoff (1987) improved these results […]. Their values for the exchange splitting are not only significantly lower but they also agree with the experimentally determined band splitting.

The references are [Gunnarsson, "Band model for magnetism of transition metals in the spin-density-functional formalism", 1976](https://www.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4608/6/4/018) and [Oles and Stollhoff, "Influence of electron correlation on the Stoner parameter and on magnetovolume effect in ferromagnetic transition metals", 1986](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-8853(86)90374-4).

Summarized from Tables 1 and 3 of Mohn and Wohlfarth's paper:

|  | Gunnarsson | Oles & Stollhoff | experimental |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fe | 5300 K | 2560 K | 1034 K |
| Co | 4000 K | 2240 K | 1388 K |
| Ni | 2900 K | 1790 K | 631 K |